# Cannot connect to VPN Server using the SoftEther VPN client over internet

Tags: networking, vpn

I set up a SoftEther VPN Server on a Windows machine. I can connect to it using the SoftEther VPN Client only in my private network but can't connect to it from a public internet network I'm getting an Error Code 1 - unable to connect to the server.

I have disable the Windows Firewall but still not working. Any thing else I could try to get the connection happening?

Comment: Did you port forward to the VPN machine? You need to open a port in your routers firewall/NAT for that to work...

Comment: i disabled both of the Firewall on the router and windows but client still not connecting to the vpn server !

Comment: You can think of NAT as if it was a company with a toll-free 1-800 number. You dial the 1-800 for the company (your external IP number) then enter an extension number (forwarded port) to reach a specific persons desk, (the computer running the VPN server). Without the extension being setup in the phone system, no one can reach that desk phone from the outside. Hopefully that analogy doesn't confuse you.